# Название кромки по краю двери

Tags: названия

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как называется эта полоса (кромка), окаймляющая дверь поверх проема?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если я правильно понял о чём идёт речь, а именно - о полосках , обрамляющих дверь с обеих сторон и сверху, то это наличники (иногда их называют "обналичники", ввиду того, что процесс их установки называется "обналичивание").

Answer (score 0):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Строительный сайт рассказывает о [калёвке](http://www.ryazan-remont.ru/sovet/16_dveri/180_konstrukcii_mezhkomnatnykh_dverejj.html), - она?

> Чтобы придать полотну затейливый вид и заодно увеличить его прочность,
>   раму нередко разделяли средниками, увеличивая число филёнок и украшая
>   их калёвкой — фигурной кромкой.

А ПОВЕРХ ПРОЁМА - совсем простенькое: ***притолока***!

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]